What's a word for feeling or being invisible (maybe in person or socially) but obviously or physically there
I'm not good at describing stuff, so I'm sorry. But is there a word that means something like feeling socially invisible yet you're not really? Like being invisible to other people despite being visible.

You mean “ socially irrelevant”?

I suppose that works

I hear low self-esteem when folks apologize for breathing.

Why do you need a word other than invisible? It can itself be very effectively used for that purpose, as long as the context makes it clear that its use is metaphorical (which will almost always be the case, as human beings are never literally invisible, outside of fairy tales and science fiction).

@jsw29 And even if they could be, saying "I feel invisible" makes it clear it's metaphorical.

Not a word for the feeling/attitude, but for the state of being insubstantial ... and not a common word ... nonentitous.

"Invisible" certainly has a literary resonance for me, thinking of Ralph Ellison's "Invisible Man." If I had more time, I would re-read it and try to pull out synonyms from there. If you read reviews/analyses of the book, you might find people using descriptive synonyms. Key quote: "I am invisible, understand, simply because people refuse to see me."

Can you rephrase that, please?
Are you suggesting 'Feeling…' and 'Being…' invisible are comparable?
Are you suggesting 'in person' and 'socially' are different here?
Are you suggesting 'obviously or physically' could need stating?

I've heard people say  "Mr Cellophane".
It's from the musical Chicago.
Here's the song: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JX5lYVqTxgI

You might call yourself a wallflower. This doesn't directly describe the emotion, but it may describe the situation:

2
  a : a person who from shyness or unpopularity remains on the sidelines of a social activity (such as a dance)
  b : a shy or reserved person

https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/wallflower
